# Which would be better for FCP and Pro Tools? Mac Mini 2.3GHz i7Quad or iMac 2.9GHz i5 Quad?

Tags: audio, imac, mac-mini, final-cut-pro

I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question.  I've been a post production recording engineer and sound editor for 20 years, but for the last 4 I've been on disability because of arthritis and Crohn's Disease and so I haven't been keeping up on the technology.  I'd like to start trying to at least do a bit of freelance work but my MacBook Pro 2.2GHz Core 2 Duo just doesn't have the muscle any more.

Keeping in mind that cost is absolutely a consideration, I'm looking at a **Mac Mini 2.3GHz i7 Quad Core 4GB RAM (*or* 2.5GHz i5 Dual Core 8GB RAM)** and a 24" Dell IPS HD monitor *or* an **iMac 2.7GHz i5 Quad Core 8GB RAM 21.5"**.  I know both monitors would be the same resolution and the iMac monitor would probably look better, but I don't know which computer is better suited to my current needs.  At least for now I'd be running *Pro Tools 8* and *FCP Studio*.  I know I'll have to learn FCPX at some point...but one thing at a time.  I don't need to have both programs open at the same time, so multi-tasking isn't a big consideration.  For the most part, data would be on external USB 3 drives.  But a couple of other questions.  Would I need to add RAM to the Mini?  Will the Mini support an IPS monitor and ALSO an HDMI monitor as a preview screen?  How much difference is Dual Core vs. Quad Core? I could get the 2.5GHz Dual Core Mini for only $600, and then add the extra RAM.

I'm one of those rabid Apple lovers so I'd obviously prefer the iMac, but I can't spend an extra couple of hundred dollars just because it'll look better on my desk.  However **LONGEVITY** is as big a concern as cost.  I'm likely going to need this computer to do the job for quite a while!  So I know that for now the software I'm using doesn't really make use of multiple cores, but newer software will right?  Other than security, is there a big difference between the i5 and i7?  Also, I don't need to start tomorrow, so what is the rumour mill saying about new release dates?  Will new iMacs have *Retina* displays?  I've checked a bunch of rumour sites but nobody has any **RELIABLE** information.

I'm sorry, I know it's a very loooong question and it seems like I've done no research on my own.  I have done some, but the answers vary greatly.  So any advice would be **GREATLY** appreciated.  If I can spend $900 dollars instead of $1300 I can eat next month (that's a joke - it's not THAT bad).  But I don't want to regret the purchase a year from now!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, **the most important** hardware component in video rendering **is videocard** (GPU).

iMac has discrete [NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-650M.71887.0.html) adapter with dedicated memory, while Mac Mini has integrated [Intel HD Graphics 4000](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-4000.69168.0.html) card. The difference is jaw-dropping. Some benchmarks to prove this:

- 3DMark 11: **2320** points in 650M, only *604* points in HD 4000.
- 3DMark 11 (GPU): **2112** points in 650M, only *524* points in HD 4000.
- 3DMark 06: **13453** points in 650M, only *4410* points in HD 4000.

I believe, you got the point. HD 4000 is a bit less powerful than NVIDIA **610M**. Quad-core processor will not matter when integrated graphics will render *every frame for 2 seconds*.

> Geekbench **is more about CPU**, than GPU. Video editing **is more about
>   GPU**, than CPU.

8 Gb of RAM is enough for working with 4K@24fps projects.

This fall new Macs will be released with better hardware and the new [OS X Mavericks](http://www.apple.com/osx/preview/) will roll out with performance (CPU and memory) improvements (more free RAM for FCPX).

So I advice you to wait for a while with buying new Mac. Get better.

Comment: That is correct (GPU is more important than CPU for video rendering)  the application i was thinking about more was Pro Tools

Answer (score 1):

According to everymac.com the mac mini configuration is more capable 
(geekbench results for 32 and 64-bit OS'es respectively)

[Mac Mini 2.3GHz i7  10626/11825*](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i7-2.3-late-2012-specs.html)

[iMac "Core i5" 2.9 21.5-Inch 9202/10756*](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.9-21-inch-aluminum-late-2012-specs.html)

personally i would add 4GB or 8GB more to the mac mini at some later time. (not at the time of buying though as apple tends to charge more than say, OWC)

I think both computers would serve you well for what you want but i would prefer the Mac mini as the iMac is a bit less capable power wise and additionally more difficult to upgrade..

Comment: That's great thanks.  But there are only 2 RAM slots right?  So if I add RAM later, don't I basically throw away the 4GB it came with?  So while Apple is more expensive, wouldn't the cost be offset by NOT having to pay for the 2 2GB chips?  Or are 3rd party that much cheaper?  According to the Apple Store, upgrading to 8GB is only $100.  What do you think?

Comment: I think you're right about RAM.  I can get a refurbished Mini with 4GB installed, pull it out and buy 16GB for $140 CDN or 8GB for $80.  One question.  How reliable is third party RAM?  Is one supplier better than another?

Comment: i would go with OWC myself (and have done...i upgraded my late 2011 MBPro  with 16 GB with absolutely no problem